# c++ time stamp identifier not found

Tags: c++, cgi

I'm trying to get a time stamp to show the system supplied date and time. I'm getting an error for 'time, 'asctime' and 'localtime' - identifier not found. I figure this should be an easy fix, but I'm a novice programmer and am beyond stuck. Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


    int main()
    {
        cout << "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
        cout << "<center><h1>TEST</h1>\n";


        return 0;

        time_t tTime = time(NULL);
    printf("Today is : %s\n", asctime(localtime(&tTime)));
    }
```

Comment: Search them on Google and you'll find what header you need to include pretty quickly.

Comment: @chris you would think so, but I have searched and still have no idea. Sad, but true.

Comment: How about at the top of [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/asctime)?

Comment: @chris - strange - my first hit on google told me which header is needed - https://www.google.com/search?q=asctime

Comment: @chris my earlier comment was for cliff, not you, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you forget to add `#include <time.h>` ?

Comment: Thanks! How would I have known to add the '.h'? *shrug*